# Having trouble scraping a specfic site with scrapy properly

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I went over the tutorial for Scrapy, and I was able to understand how to scrap the site included in the tutorial. But I'm having a little trouble with some of the more complicated sites (at least to me).

I'm attempting to scrape the rows and columns of the insider transactions from this webpage:

http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx

I'm using command prompt commands with scrapy to test out if I'm able to scrape the necessary information, so the following commands are what I've have written in the command prompt.

```
scrapy shell "http://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx"
```

I then used firebug from firefox to look at the html code of the page.

I'm able to get some of the information (Stock Name, Name of the Insider and Date) into a list via this code:

```
response.css('td a.tab-link::text').extract()
```

However, the rest of the info is missing.

I'm able to get some (maybe most)of the missing info (Cost, Shares, Value etc) via this code

```
response.css(td::text).extract()
```

I can't figure out how to cleanly get all info together in one scrape.

Thanks.

EDIT: The other option would be to collect the data iteratively, one row at a time, so I can separate it as I like. I'm brooding over this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is tabular, the position of table rows and columns is predictable and stable. You can simply extract all text in the row and unpack it into variables:

```
for row in response.xpath("//tr[@class='insider-option-row']"):
    items = row.xpath('td/a/text() | td/text()').extract()
    ticker, owner, relationship, date, transaction, cost, shares, value, shares_total, sec_form_4 = items
```